# Cefsharp installation crashes on installation, but running through VS

Tags: c#, winforms, clickonce, cefsharp

I wanted to use chrome in my WinForms applications. 
This is what I have done:-

1. Created application.
2. Downloaded and installed Cefsharp.Winforms (53.0.1)

   ```
   It added following:-
   ```

In app.config I added following:-

```
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <probing privatePath="x86"/>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
```

3. Build the project and used the code to load my html page.

Now, the project runs absolutely fine when debugging from Visual Studio, after that I go and use publish wizard to create an installer. As soon as the installation completed, it shows the same old common message box saying "ApplicationXYZ has stopped working."
I have made sure that VC++ runtime is installed. But it's not even installing on my machine.

Note: I tried a new app without Cefsharp "ChromiumWebBrowser", and it runs and installs just fine, it's only when I use cefsharp that I get the error after installation. (Let me repeat however, it does run fine while debugging and all in VS 2015).

Any help and pointer will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Search the `GitHub` project for instructions on packing your application with `ClickOnce`, you have to manually include the `unamanged` dlls.

Comment: Thanks, that helped!